# How come this code does not deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Shouldn't the Log method block?

```
namespace Sandbox {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var log = new Logger();
        lock (log) {
            log.Log("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}

public class Logger {
    public void Log(string message) {
        lock (this) {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lock aqcuired and further attempts to lock do not block: are C# locks re-entrant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846010/lock-aqcuired-and-further-attempts-to-lock-do-not-block-are-c-locks-re-entrant)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The *same thread* is acquiring the same lock twice. This works because .NET supports so-called recursive locks (aka [reentrant mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex)).

Comment: Can we rely on this behavior staying in C#? It makes things simpler, but since I did not see it mentioned in MSDN docs I am wondering if this is an implementation side effect that can change in the future.

Answer (score 4):

If a resource is locked by a thread, that thread is allowed in, even if it already owns a lock on it. The same is true for this

```
Object obj = new Object();

lock(obj) {
    lock(obj) {
        foo();
    }
}
```

Would lock out if you couldn't get through by virtue of being the same thread.

Answer (score 3):

Simple - you are running in a single thread.