# c# .net 4.8 winforms. Lock object can be locked several times simultaneously in simple single thread app

Tags: c#, locking

Duplicate question. Answer here ...

[Lock aqcuired and further attempts to lock do not block: are C# locks re-entrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846010/lock-aqcuired-and-further-attempts-to-lock-do-not-block-are-c-sharp-locks-re-en)

Basically (copied from link above):

Locks in .NET are reentrant. Only acquisitions from other threads are blocked. When the same thread locks the same object multiple times, it simply increments a counter, and decrements it when released. When the counter hits zero, the lock is actually released for access from other threads.

---

c# .net 4.8 winforms. One button, one multiline textbox.

Simple app - click on button, it waits 2 seconds (doevents for 2 seconds), it writes out.

I clicked the button 6 times, about a second apart. I am aware the doevents allows more click events to be picked up. I can see that the lock is not waiting before processing is finished for previous click., and that the events are finishing in reverse order.

Q1 - Why is the lock not locking?

Q2 - why are the click events completed in reverse order?

Q3 -What's actually happening here?

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_testlock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        object _objLock;
        int _intIteration;
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, DateTime> _lstIterationsTimes;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            _objLock = new object();
            _intIteration = 0;
            _lstIterationsTimes = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _intIteration++;
            _lstIterationsTimes.Add(_intIteration, DateTime.Now);
            Process(_intIteration);
        }

        private void Process(int intIteration)
        {
            textBox1.Text += "About to lock - " + intIteration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            lock (_objLock)
            {
                textBox1.Text += "Succeeded to lock - " + intIteration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                

                while ( (DateTime.Now - _lstIterationsTimes[intIteration]).TotalSeconds < 2)
                {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                textBox1.Text += "About to unlock - " + intIteration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine ;
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

About to lock - 1

Succeeded to lock - 1

About to lock - 2

Succeeded to lock - 2

About to lock - 3

Succeeded to lock - 3

About to lock - 4

Succeeded to lock - 4

About to lock - 5

Succeeded to lock - 5

About to lock - 6

Succeeded to lock - 6

About to unlock - 6

About to unlock - 5

About to unlock - 4

About to unlock - 3

About to unlock - 2

About to unlock - 1

Comment: Sounds like it's all happening on the same thread, in which case the `lock` isn't blocking.

Comment: Thanks - I already added that to the top as a duplicate ref! So while here, why are the events in reverse order? Do messages get processed with more recent first?

Comment: Loosely: each time the thread calls `Process` it enters the lock, you call `Application.DoEvents();` which allows the same thread to call `Process`, entering the lock again. As it's the same thread, there's no blocking. At the end, you're in `DoEvents()` multiple times - but no thread has left the lock. Then the innermost call (6) leaves the lock and exits `Process`, then the next-innermost (5), etc. until (1) leaves.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Thanks sounds a tiny bit confusing. "No thread has left the lock" -there's only thread. This doesn't really explain the reverse order.

Comment: Whoops - apologies. That was poorly-worded. Maybe it'd be better if I posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1 - Why is the lock not locking?

When you press button1 the call to `button1_Click` is always on the same thread, the GUI thread. In C# a thread may enter the same lock multiple times.

> Q2 - why are the click events completed in reverse order?

> Q3 -What's actually happening here?

See below.

---

What is happening, and why, can be summarised in the following image (apologies for the appalling quality - I did this in PowerPoint) - to keep things simple, I've limited the number of times that the `Process` method is called to three:

[image]

What's happening is the following - all on the GUI thread:

- `button1_Click` is triggered, which increments `_intIteration` to `1` then calls `Process(1)`.
- Inside `Process(1)`:

  - The lock is entered immediately as there is no other thread in the lock.
  - Within the `while` loop, the application is allowed to await input from the user through the repeated calls to `DoEvents()`.
  - At some point during `while` loop, button1 is clicked again. The `DoEvents()` call doesn't return until `button1_Click` returns.
  - `button1_Click` is triggered, which increments `_intIteration` to `2` then calls `Process(2)`.
  - Inside `Process(2)` (still on the GUI thread):

    - The lock is entered immediately as there is no other thread in the lock - this thread has entered the lock **once** already, but a single thread can re-enter the same lock multiple times.
    - Within the `while` loop, the application is allowed to await input from the user through the repeated calls to `DoEvents()`.
    - At some point during `while` loop, button1 is clicked again. The `DoEvents()` call doesn't return until `button1_Click` returns.
    - `button1_Click` is triggered, which increments `_intIteration` to `3` then calls `Process(3)`.
    - Inside `Process(3)` (still on the GUI thread):

      - The lock is entered immediately as there is no other thread in the lock - this thread has entered the lock **twice** already, but a single thread can re-enter the same lock multiple times.
      - Within the `while` loop, the application is allowed to await input from the user through the repeated calls to `DoEvents()`.
      - No user interation happens, so `Process(3)` returns after printing "About to unlock - 3"
    - The third level of `button1_Click` returns as `Process(3)` returned.
    - `DoEvents()` (called from `Process(2)`) returns so the execution returns to `Process(2)`.
  - `Process(2)` returns after printing "About to unlock - 2"
  - The second level of `button1_Click` returns as `Process(2)` returned.
- `DoEvents()` (called from `Process(1)`) returns so the execution returns to `Process(1)`.
- `Process(1)` returns after printing "About to unlock - 1"
- The first level of `button1_Click` returns as `Process(1)` returned.

Note that once button1 stops being clicked and the `while` loops exit, there are multiple stack frames in the `DoEvents()` method. The methods **must** exit in a last in, first out order which is why `Process(3)` exits then `Process(2)` exits then `Process(1)` exits, resulting in the

```
About to unlock - 3

About to unlock - 2

About to unlock - 1
```

that you are unsure about.

---

As this all happens on one thread, it might be easier to look at the following code which shows you what's happening:

```
private static object _objLock = new object();

public static void Main(params string[] arguments)
{
    Recurse(1);
}

public static void Recurse(int iteration)
{
    if ( iteration > 3 )
        return;

    Console.WriteLine($"About to lock - {iteration}");

    lock ( _objLock )
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Entered lock - {iteration}");

        Recurse(iteration + 1);

        Console.WriteLine($"Releasing lock - {iteration}");
    }
}
```

which writes this to the console:

```
About to lock - 1
Entered lock - 1
About to lock - 2
Entered lock - 2
About to lock - 3
Entered lock - 3
Releasing lock - 3
Releasing lock - 2
Releasing lock - 1
```

Comment: You've put alot of effort in there! Thanks very much. I think my thoughts are that as there is only one thread, the lock is insignificant, and the lock-related code can be removed. I'm happy with the explanation of the lock not blocking - it only offers value in a multi-thread application. I've now read your stuff about the reversal order, and can understand that now. The key is the doevents. It checks for messages in the message queue; if there are messages, IT IMMEDIATELY STOPS AT THAT POINT WHAT IT CURRENTLY HAPPENING, dequeues the message and actions it. It's the stopping  didn't realise

Comment: @fangled: Yes - that's right: `DoEvents()` is what causes the thread to jump from one method to another before continuing, which is how the lock can be entered multiple times by that thread... *If* you found my answer was helpful, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it (only if you want).